# NoSuchElementExcpetion thrown even when I catch it?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm not clear why I still get a NoSuchElementException thrown in this Webdriver test?

Can anyone debug or suggest a more efficient/robyst solution?

NB - I get the same error if I try a driver.findElements( By.id("...") ).size() != 0

```
    boolean present;
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".message-bg-color>table>tbody>tr>td>h3"));
        present = true;
    }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        present = false;
    }

    if(!present) {

       // do some stuff
    }
     else 
    { 
       //do some otherstuff
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".message-bg-color>table>tbody>tr>td>h3"}
Command duration or timeout: 1.17 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'L-IS08381', ip: '172.19.248.194', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 203c9fbc-3b59-4c6e-9f6b-03738b1c1c8f
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=28.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at cms.workflow.DeleteArticleSysadminTest.deleteTestArtifactTest(DeleteArticleSysadminTest.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".message-bg-color>table>tbody>tr>td>h3"}
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'L-IS08381', ip: '172.19.248.194', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
```

Comment: I think you should share some more of your code. Check the error stack for the specific line where the `NoSuchElementException` is happening.

Comment: You might want to check out [this](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) lightweight java debugging tutorial (full disclosure: I wrote it. It seems to fit your needs)

Comment: @wns349 - it's being thrown from line 3 in the attached snippet, i.e. were it tries to find the element.

Comment: Could you post your stack trace? `NoSuchElementException` might have already been handled within your `findElement` method by printing out stack trace or something perhaps.. :s Otherwise, try changing your 4th line from `catch (NoSuchElementException e)` to `catch(Exception e)` and see what happens...

Comment: @wns349 done. thanks.  If I replace with    catch(Exception e) then the test passes.  I think I need to learn why this happens!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your code's `NoSuchElementException` is of type `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`.

It is very likely that you might have used `java.util.NoSuchElementException` instead.

You could try adding `import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` on top of your source code.